# Unexpected column with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble with my database generated with Entity Framework.
In my database, I want to have the following data:

- Table with `TestRequests` and a table of `Users`
- Each `User` can be the `Author` of one or more `TestRequests`, but 1 `TestRequest` can only have 1 `Author`.

I'm using Entity Framework Core and the .NET Command-line Tools v7.0.11.

Those are my classes:

```
public class TestRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public TestRequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public List<ItemNumber> ItemNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<SerialNumber> SerialNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<Norm> Norms { get; set; }
    public List<User> Developers { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; } 

    public ICollection<CommentaryModel> Comments { get; set; } = new List<CommentaryModel>();
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public AuthorizationStatus AuthorizationStatus { get; set; }
    public string AuthorizationMessage { get; set; }
    public User AuthorizationByUser { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public List<TestRequest> TestRequests { get; set; } 
}
```

In my Application `DbContext`:

```
. . .
public DbSet<TestRequest> TestRequests { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
. . .
```

I am expecting a table `Users` without anything regarding `TestRequests`. And a table `TestRequests` with an FK `Author` referencing the `User ID`, OR a third table linking `TestRequests` with an `User`.

But instead I get this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Users",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        LastName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        FirstName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        AuthorizationStatusId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        AuthorizationMessage = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        AuthorizationByUserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        TestRequestId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Users_AuthorizationStates_AuthorizationStatusId",
            column: x => x.AuthorizationStatusId,
            principalTable: "AuthorizationStates",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Users_Roles_RoleId",
            column: x => x.RoleId,
            principalTable: "Roles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Users_TestRequests_TestRequestId",
            column: x => x.TestRequestId,
            principalTable: "TestRequests",
            principalColumn: "Id");
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Users_Users_AuthorizationByUserId",
            column: x => x.AuthorizationByUserId,
            principalTable: "Users",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });
```

The problem is the `TestRequestId` as a column in the table `Users`.

I tried dropping the database several times, removing all migrations, build new, clean all...

I don't know what I'm missing. Do you guys know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

EF Core does not know that the `Author` property in your `TestRequest` has anything to do with the list of `TestRequests` a user has. Because of this it creates two relationships instead of one.

You can tell EF Core that these two properties share one relationship by using the FluentAPI. Add the following piece of code to `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestRequest>()
            .HasOne<User>(tr => tr.Author)
            .WithMany(u => u.TestRequests);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!

Unfortunately this did not work and had the same effect. 
I dropped the whole database, removed migrations and added a new migration after i made your suggested changes.

But it still made the unexpected column in the Users Table

Comment: Now that I took a closer look at the TestResult class I noticed that it also has a list of users (developers).  This is why the user column also has a TestRequest id.

Comment: Yeah thats right i removed the developers to test it and it worked. But i need it. Do you have a suggestion how i can do it with modelbuilder? 
Its just that every user can be the developer of more Testrequests and a Testrequest can hold more than one user

Comment: I'm thinking you already have a working solution, but for some reason believe that it's wrong.

Comment: Well theres a column TestRequestId in Users. That would be right if each User could only be a "Developer" in a single TestRequest, but each User can be a "Developer" in many TestRequests. At least thats what i want :D

Or am i missing some basic information about entity framework / databases?